# AWS CLI: Error when trying to retrieve console output of an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

When retrieving the console output for an instance with this command:

`aws ec2 --region us-east-1b get-console-output --instance-id my_instance_id`

I got following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries
exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddr
info failed).
```

Comment: I even tried with source: 0.0.0.0 still no change.

Comment: For PuTTY: Did you configured PuTTY with the EC2 private key? See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: Yeah. I followed the same documentation.

Comment: can you show me the `aws cli` command you run to connect ec2 instance? And run `aws ec2 describe-instances`, any errors?

Comment: For the Putty issue, mostly you didn't set properly, you need read that url again.

Comment: aws ec2 --region us-east-1b get-console-output --instance-id my_instance_id

Comment: der might have been some issue with key. I created new instance & now it's running fine. So that issue is resolved. but cli is still der, even for new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this. One of my friends helped me. There was a problem with key. Key needed for the instance was the one which I created while creating instance, not the one which I changed afterwards. So, it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure your 'aws', ensure the region name is given correctly.

```
C:\>aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************OFFQ]: 
AWS Secret Access Key [****************AXeN]: 
Default region name [None]: us-east-1b
Default output format [None]:
```

Comment: The issue has been resolved now. But thanks for your help. Issue was with key. So I made new instance with new key & it's working fine now.